# How to remove weird spot on material

Tags: materials

I keep having this weird twirl/spiral spot appearing on my object. How can I remove it? It moved location when I join all 4 objects to create 1.[image]

[image]

Comment: What does the mesh look like in edit mode?

Comment: I don't see any inconsistencies in the wire frame. I could be wrong, but I'm convinced it's something to do with the material.

Answer (score 3):

Turn off the "anisotropic" in you material, that is a factor for radial brush patterns in metal.

Comment: THAT'S IT!! Thank you!!